# Order Array With Custom Object in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an Array called "myArray". In this array I have several objects from a custom NSObject class where I have 2 properties named "name" and "age".
Now I want to sort the objects in the Array in alphabetic order by the property "name". I know how to do this in Objective-C but I really don't have an idea how to do this in Swift.
Would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't see that - thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation of sort should be what you are looking for:

```
array.sort({
    $0.name < $1.name
})
```